# Tab Bar Controller Will Not Display Tabs Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7-beta2

For some reason in Xcode 7 the tab bar controller won't default with displayed tab icons. I'd like to determine if this is an issue with my default settings, or if this is a change in Xcode 7 from Xcode 6 in which I'll have to manually add the tab icons to the bottom of the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive noticed that too.

You have to go into attribute inspector for the tab item and choose . The system type will be on custom which is why your not seeing any icons.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. I'd like to use Custom system item, as I have a custom image. But can't figure out how to make this work.